# Angular: what is the difference between '=' and '=?' while defining a scope in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am just picking up selectize example

```
    angular.module('selectize', []).value('selectizeConfig', {}).directive("selectize", ['selectizeConfig', function(selectizeConfig) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^ngModel',
        scope: { 
          ngModel: '=', 
          config: '=?', 
          options: '=?', 
          ngDisabled: '=', 
          ngRequired: '&' 
        },
link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {...}
```

I know '=' will map existing controller scope's property in two way but what about '=?' ?

Comment: `=?` is make it optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope: {foo: '=?'}
```

means  'do not raise error if 'foo' cannot be resolved.

> The 'isolate' scope takes an object hash which defines a set of local
>   scope properties derived from the parent scope. These local properties
>   are useful for aliasing values for templates. Locals definition is a
>   hash of local scope property to its source:
>
> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value
>   of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute
>   name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given   and widget definition of

```
scope: {  
localModel:'=myAttr' },
```

> then widget scope property localModel will
>   reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to 
>   parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in 
>   localModel will reflect in parentModel. If the parent scope property
>   doesn't exist, it will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION
>   exception. You can avoid this behavior using

```
=? or =?attr
```

> in order to flag the property as optional.

Answer (score 2):

`=` or `=attr` set's up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and parent scope property, If the parent `scope` property doesn't exist, it will throw a `NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION` exception.

This can avoid this behavior using `=?` or `=?attr` in order to flag the property as **optional**